# Mean Squared Error (MSE) equivalence to trace + bias on multivariate case

Tags: multivariate-analysis, bias, covariance-matrix, estimators

I'm trying to show that:
$$
MSE(\theta)\equiv E[(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta)'(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta)]=tr(V(\hat{\theta}_n))+Bias(\hat{\theta}_n)'Bias(\hat{\theta}_n)
$$
where $Bias(\hat{\theta}_n)=E(\hat{\theta}_n)-\theta$ and $tr(V(\hat{\theta}_n))$ is the trace of variance-covariance matrix of the estimator, $\hat{\theta}_n$ is the estimator and $\theta$ is the population parameter we're trying to estimate.

I have managed to show that:
$$
E[(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta)'(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta)]=\left[tr(V(\hat{\theta}_n))+Bias(\hat{\theta}_n)'Bias(\hat{\theta}_n)\right] +\left[E(\hat{\theta}_n-E(\hat{\theta}_n))'Bias(\hat{\theta}_n)+Bias(\hat{\theta}_n)'E(\hat{\theta}_n-E(\hat{\theta}_n))\right]
$$

**Question**: what do I do with the extra term above? Why is it zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize that:
$$
E(\hat{\theta}_n-E(\hat{\theta}_n))'=E(\hat{\theta}_n)'-E(E(\hat{\theta}_n))'=E(\hat{\theta}_n)'-E(\hat{\theta}_n)'=0
$$